# mybatis select record between two time

Tags: mysql, mybatis

I use MyBatis in my project,when I get a problem like below, I don't know how to pass two parameters to the query, it always tell me that the parameter is not found, I don't know why,
appreciate for you help.
**configure Mapper:**

```html
  @Select("select * from tq_configure_pacific where visitTime between #{dateFrom,jdbcType=DATE}        and  #{dateTo,jdbcType=DATE}")
    @Options(flushCache = true)
    List<configure> selectConfigureByTime(Date dateFrom,Date dateTo);
```

**configurMapper.xml**

```html
 <select id="selectConfigure2" >
  select * from tq_configure_pacific where visitTime between #{dateFrom,jdbcType=DATE}  and  #{dateTo,jdbcType=DATE}
  </select>
```

**main function:**

```html
public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException, IOException{
        Reader reader = Resources.getResourceAsReader("mybatis-config.xml");
        SqlSessionFactory sessionFactory = new SqlSessionFactoryBuilder().build(reader);
        SqlSession session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        try{
            configureMapper mapper = session.getMapper(configureMapper.class);
//            configure conf = mapper.selectConfigureById(500);
            Calendar cal=Calendar.getInstance();
            long nextday=cal.getTime().getTime()+24*60*60*1000;
            Date visitDate=new java.sql.Date(cal.getTime().getTime());
            Date validDate=new java.sql.Date(nextday);
            System.out.println(visitDate);
            System.out.println(validDate);
            List<configure> conf2 = mapper.selectConfigureByTime(visitDate,validDate);
            for(configure confg:conf2)
            {
                System.out.println(confg.getId()+"=="+confg.getValidTime());
            }
//            System.out.println("Source name:"+conf2.getSource());
        }finally{
            session.close();
        }
    
    }
```

**I get this problem:**

```html
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.ibatis.exceptions.PersistenceException: 
### Error querying database.  Cause: org.apache.ibatis.binding.BindingException: Parameter 'dateFrom' not found. Available parameters are [0, 1, param1, param2]
### Cause: org.apache.ibatis.binding.BindingException: Parameter 'dateFrom' not found. Available parameters are [0, 1, param1, param2]
```

**Did I do anything wrong?**

Answer (score 2):

MyBatis cannot detect params by the java method parameter names. So if there is more than 1 parameter in your method you should annotate them with `org.apache.ibatis.annotations.Param` annotation:

```java
List<configure> selectConfigureByTime(@Param("dateFrom") Date dateFrom, @Param("dateTo") Date dateTo);
```